# Fetching related objects with Laravel and Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I created some models in Laravel extending the Eloquent class. In these models I added relations, like in this example:

```
//in the User class
public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Group');
}
```

in this way I'm able to retrieve the group object for a specific user in this simply way:

```
User::find(1)->group
```

and this is nice. I need to fetch the entire table and display it in json format, so I do

```
User::all()->toJson()
```

I obtain the whole table, but I have the "group_id" column instead of the group object. Is there a simple way to include related object in JSON? I know that I can loop in the collection and manually add the object, but I think that should be bad practice because I need to do a lot of query, when this problem can be solved using a single query with a join. Any idea?

Comment: Please accept your working answer by clicking the hollow check mark next to it instead of changing the question title. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe eager loading is what you're looking for: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading

`User::with('group')->get()->toJson()`

**Edit:** fixing call to `get()` from `all()`

Comment: Thank you very much, but the method all doesn't exist. It works fine with User::with('group')->get()->toJson()

Answer (score 0):

Soved!

```
User::with('group')->get()->toJson()
```

Comment: You should accept the answer from @Nathan Loding instead of posting the same answer yourself

Comment: @Albin: What are you saying? The code from Nathan is different from mine and it doesn't work! Please read the code with attention...